# Future in indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

In my English book for Russian students, I have found a confusing sentence:

*A second conference will be held tomorrow morning and Brigg's agent said that an interview ________ (give) by the actor over the coming days.*

The key says that the answer is **will be given** but I don't really understand why not **would be given**. Isn't it a reported speech sentence with the future clause where we need to replace *will* with *would*?

Really need your explanation:( Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion might stem from the fact that [we often change *will* to *would* in reported speech](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/):

> "I will go to Zurich tomorrow," he said.
>   He said that he would go to Zurich tomorrow.

This is often referred to as "[future-in-the-past](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html)".

However, I find that to be *less and less true all the time, at least in US English, particularly when we're talking about future plans that are still true*:

> In 1998, Elaine said, "I **will** go to France next year."
>   In 1998, Elaine said that she **would** go to France next year.

BUT

> Today, Zahra said, "The house **will** be completed in 2020."
>   Today, Zahra said that the house **will** be completed in 2020.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the clue lies in the words "over the coming days". Sometimes you have to take meaning from the entire sentence. These words indicate to me an impending certainty. If they were not there then I would have used 'would be given' and *would* always has a little doubt to it. But, because you have 'over the coming days' then it makes sense to use 'will be given'.

Furthermore, the first part of the phrase is in the future perfect: A second conference **will be held**. the second part of the sentence is indtroduced by an 'and', so perhaps a future perfect construction overrides the indirect speech aspect. Though I am not completely sure on that. However, '**will be given**' is absolutely the correct answer here.